# Hourly or daily rate for consulting?

Tags: pay-rate, consulting, price-per-hour, hourly

I have started my own consultancy business and have been asked to do two things for a client:

1. Provide assistance around how to manage data in an existing system
2. Provide training around database development

The client definitely wants both of these options carried out and, at first glance, I would think that option 1 would warrant an hourly rate and option 2 would warrant a daily rate.

In terms of what to charge per hour / day (consulting) / day (training), I am rather uncertain as I cannot find any guidance as to what the typical rates tend to be - what do experienced data consultants charge in such instances?

Although, the more I think about it, the more uncertain I become - what tends to be the case in such scenarios and what questions should I ask myself?

Comment: I am afraid that if you change per hour, the client will want to watch how much time you spent on the toilett, stopping to drink water and this small things, because he will be aware that all of this small moments added together corresponds to 1.5 hours per day, and might feel tempted to discount that on you. If you charge per week (or day), he is less likely to come with those ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the daily rate if you can do it that way. You will earn more. However, I think that the client will propose hourly rate for both things.

Now, about the hourly rate, it's impossible to tell how much to charge. Even if you and me are from the same town, we would not charge the same.

So just do what other freelancers do: count your costs and add profit to costs total and that will be your hourly rate.

In time, you will know if it's enough or you need to raise it. It's impossible to get the correct rate immediately.

Aside of this, you can visit freelancers services and find contractors from your area and see how much they charge. Also try to find a small company from your region (the best would be a company with just a few workers), and see who much they charge.

Lastly, there is no typical rate. Your rate is as high as you are able to sell it to the client. So you can get $10/h from one client and then $110/h from another. You will realize soon that freelancers are very similar to car sellers :).

Comment: Thank you, Peter - there are some really helpful comments here.  By your logic, I take it to mean that I should charge a day rate because I will earn £1,000 regardless of how long I am with my client as opposed to if they only need me for two hours at £200ph - is this correct? (Great car seller analogy, by the way!)

Comment: You can try, but I doubt they will accept that. So try this first. If they complain or says it's too much, then propose hourly rate approach. Again noone can tell you how much to charge. I can only tell you what to count in. But yes, you can offer higher hourly rate approach if you want. Not bad idea at all.

Comment: I don't think this is true. I have a daily rate that is based on my experience and market prices, nothing random about it. Also: daily rates don't mean you can charge for an entire day even if you don't actually do a day's work. If your daily rate is 800 for an 8 hour day and you only work 6, you charge 600.